# Same template for all the terms of a taxonomy

Tags: templates, taxonomy, archives

My problem is the following.

I have a custom post type called "photography" which contains a taxonomy called "photographyCategories", which contains several terms : "outside", "inside", "portrait"...

All these terms content is based on the same outline (a list of pictures and a slider).

I know that if I want to display the archive page of one of these terms I have to create, for example, the file taxonomy-photographyCategories-outside.php. I've done it and it works.

But what I want is ONE template for all these terms. I don't wanna have an "outside" template, an "inside" template and a "portrait" template because they're all the same... They display the same type of content, except the photographies that are different.

I can't find a way to do this...

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) you have to create the template

```
taxonomy-photographyCategories.php
```

Comment: That's what I've done. But this is the template page for my taxonomy "photographyCategories" which displays a list of all the terms.

Comment: Why would I rename it ?
I want to keep this page, and I wanna create another one which would be a term template.
But may be the solution is very simple like... Setting a variable in the URL ?

Comment: I think you gave me an beginning of solution.
When I click on `portrait` on my taxonomy archive page `taxonomy-photographyCategories.php`, it redirects me to this link : `wordpress/photographieCategories/portraits/`.
So as you said, if the `portraits` template exists, it's used. But can I create a "common" template like `photographieTerms.php` which would be used ? And within this template I would get a variable in the URL (imagine `photographieTerms.php?term=portrait`) to know what term has been clicked ?

Comment: Please **post in the question the code you have in `taxonomy-photographyCategories.php` and the code you have in one term template** because the "common" template you are looking for normally is just `taxonomy-photographyCategories.php`: when you visit  `wordpress/photographieCategories/portraits/` that file is used if it exists and if `taxonomy-photographyCategories-portraits.php` doesn't exists. So, remove the file `taxonomy-photographyCategories-portraits.php` and use some conditional in `taxonomy-photographyCategories.php` to appear differently if you are vising a term or not. @Valentin

Comment: Okay I have my answer !
My question was too complicated for this simple solution...
Thank you for helping :)